# OLE bstr not null terminated?

Tags: c++, excel, com, ole, idispatch

So, I am trying to automate Excel from C++ and OLE, using the `Autowrap` function provided by Microsoft in their automation examples.

I have gotten as far as that I can read a string value from a cell in the spreadsheet. However, it seems like for some values, something is wrong with the string, like it's not null terminated. Here is my code:

```
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, range, L"Value", 0);
wprintf(L"%s, len: %d\n", result.bstrVal, SysStringLen(result.bstrVal));
wprintf(L"abc %s\n", SysAllocString(L"def"));
```

The output is:

```
John Doe  á, 11
abc def
```

Whereas, in the Excel file when displayed in Excel, it shows like:

```
John Doe
```

(Can the code page of the Excel document somehow be an issue? It's an `xlsx` file.)

Comment: Can you try that with `L"Value2"`?

Comment: @Amit, exactly same result!

Comment: 1. Does that happen with any cell / value? 2 What do you get with `SysStringLen(results.bstrVal)`? 3. What do you get if you try `wprintf(L"abc %s\n", SysAllocString(L"def"));`?

Comment: @Amit, updated question. 1 - no, it does not happen always, just for some values.

Comment: and the `LEN()` function inside excel shows "8" I presume?

Comment: @Amit, actually 11!  So I guess data is dirty somehow in the cell... ?!

Comment: I guess so... maybe it's excel that's hiding that extra characters

Comment: I pasted the cell value into a text file, then viewed it with Double Commanders hex viewer. The last character is a non breaking space. (Hex A0). So that was the culprit all along... @Amit

Comment: @Amit, so I guess the console can not display non breaking space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> John Doe  á, 11

Code is pretty buggy and needs to be fixed.  The *result* variable cannot be IDispatch, it must be a `VARIANT`.  You blindly assume that the Range.Cell.Value property returns a string, that's not how Excel works.  Calling VariantChangeType() to force a conversion to `VT_BSTR` is required.

The `á` character is otherwise a simple text encoding problem.  Dollars to donuts, you copied the string from a console window.  Which uses [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) by default in Western Europe and the Americas.  The character code for á in that code page is 0xA0.  Which is *actually* U+00A0, a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in Unicode, not an unusual codepoint in modern text.

Getting it to actually display as a space in a console mode app requires calling SetConsoleOutputCP() to switch it to `CP_UTF8` and changing the font of the console from Terminal to a TrueType font like Consolas.  Well covered in other Q+A at this site.

Comment: Thank you. I will not need to actually display it, but I will account for proper unicode string handling in my program and above all fix the VARIANT bug.

Comment: Hm, I pasted in the code incorrectly. `result` was a `VARIANT` all along. But the string conversion call needed to ensure a string type, I had no idea about.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149605/writing-cell-in-excel-from-c-no-value-written-cell-is-blank too?