# Writing cell in Excel from C++ - no value written, cell is blank

Tags: c++, excel, com, ole, variant

When I write a cell from C++ with OLE to a cell in Excel, I get an empty cell. Whatever value is there gets overwritten to be blank. It writes in the correct cell though, so it seems the range is correct. This is my code.

```
VARIANT arr;
BSTR val = SysAllocString(L"hello excel world");
_bstr_t(val, false);
arr.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;

SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[1];
sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 1;
arr.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, sab);
long indices[] = {1, 1};
SafeArrayPutElement(arr.parray, indices, (void*)&val);

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, range, L"Value", 1, arr);
```

Comment: Is there any point in using an array when you simply want to write a string?  Note [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/05/04/126190.aspx) for the rocket science, you need a two-dimensional array.

Comment: No point, I got that idea from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216686

Comment: @HansPassant, I changed to     SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
    sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 1;
    sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 1;
    arr.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
       but still same result

Comment: @HansPassant, you put me on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand how to correctly pass an argument to Excel. It needs to be a variant, not a naked BSTR:

```
VARIANT arr;
BSTR val = SysAllocString(L"hello excel world");
_bstr_t(val, false);
arr.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;

SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 1;
sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 1;
arr.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
long indices[] = {1, 1};
VARIANT valvariant;
valvariant.vt = VT_BSTR;
valvariant.bstrVal = val;

SafeArrayPutElement(arr.parray, indices, (void*)&valvariant);

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, range, L"Value", 1, arr);
```